# Hibernate lazy loading doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lazy-loading

I have some problems with Hibernate lazy loading. See below my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "diagnoses")
public class Diagnosis extends Domain implements IDiagnosis {

    @Column(name = "short_name")
    private String shortName;

    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private int code;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Anamnesis.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "diagnoses_id", nullable = false)
    private Set<IAnamnesis> anamneses = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Complaint.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "diagnoses_id", nullable = false)
    private Set<IComplaint> complaints = new HashSet<>();
        ...
}
```

but when I invoke in test findAll() or findById() method, hibernate initialize collections...

```
@Service("diagnosisService")
public class DiagnosisService implements IDiagnosisService {

    @Autowired
    private IDiagnosisRepository diagnosisRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public IDiagnosis getById(String id) {
        return diagnosisRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public boolean saveOrUpdate(IDiagnosis diagnosis) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (diagnosis != null) {
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(diagnosis.getId())) {
                diagnosisRepository.insert(diagnosis);
                result = true;
            } else {
                diagnosisRepository.update(diagnosis);
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public boolean delete(IDiagnosis diagnosis) {
        boolean deleted = false;
        if (diagnosis != null) {
            diagnosisRepository.delete(diagnosis);
            deleted = true;
        }
        return deleted;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
    public List<IDiagnosis> getAll() {
        return diagnosisRepository.findAll();
    }



public class DiagnosisRepository{
... 
    public T findById(ID id) {
        T t = null;
        List<T> data = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(String.format("from %s where id='%s'",
            getClassName(), id)).list();
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(data)) {
            t = data.get(FIRST_ENTITY);
        }
        return t;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(String.format("from %s", getClassName())).list();
    }
... 
}
```

I use Hibernate 4. Why is this happening? maybe it has additional settings?

Comment: Well, if you mention (describe) clearly what happens when you use `FetchType.LAZY` (or `FetchType.EAGER`) and what you expect then it is possible for someone to answer the question. It is certainly not clear  only with the code snippets you posted.

Comment: Sorry, if my question is not enough clearly for understanding. I use LAZY fetch type, but all fields in my entity initialized when i invoke some methods for retriveing my entities. I my case when i invoke "getById" method then i get IDiagnosis entity the "anamneses" collection already initialized as if I use the EAGER fetch type. Sory for my bad english, i'm not native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

And why do you think it is initialized? While you debug do you see the initialized field in the collection set to true? Have you tried accessing the collection outside the transaction. It should through a LazyInitializationException.

Btw [Onetomany](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html) mappings are lazy by default. You need not explicitly mention it.